# MySQLI STMT Num_rows

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been having a problem with the prepared statements in MySQLI OOP. The problem is that I don't know how to use the num_rows() method correct.
If I use var_dump to see the result of the variables I will get NULL because there is no data.

```
 $stringMail    = trim($_POST['mail']);
 /* 
 .....
 */
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ? ");
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $stringMail);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();
 $stmt->bind_result($usersMail);
 $iaMail = $stmt->num_rows;
 $stmt->close();
```

Sorry for the bad English, I'm Dutch and my English isn't the very best... Thanks for helping!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you meen by putting store_result befote num_rows? In my code I've already done that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need it. As you have `$usersMail` already.

Comment: Possibly true, but hardly an answer to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry but that still wil give me NULL.

Comment: @RezaM It's all right. If `$usersMail` is giving you null, that means  no record were returned.

Comment: I'm such a noob... Thnx for helping me, I've tried it out by testing my system and It seems to work now! :-)